# Windows resource file makes programme require admin privileges

Tags: windows, mingw

I'm compiling a windows programme and linking it up under MinGW / MSYS

If I compile a basic resource file from

```
id ICON "foobar.ico"
```

with windres, then link it up, all is good and my programme acquires an icon.

If I use a .rc file suggested in various places on the net, including on here:

```
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     1,0,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION  1,0,0,0
BEGIN
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    BLOCK "080904E4"
    BEGIN
      VALUE "CompanyName", "Foo Ltd"
      VALUE "FileDescription", "blah blah"
      VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0"
      VALUE "InternalName", "foo_tool"
      VALUE "LegalCopyright", "me"
      VALUE "OriginalFilename", "foobar.exe"
      VALUE "ProductName", "FooBar Tool"
      VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0"
    END
  END

  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x809, 1252
  END
END

id ICON "foo.ico"
```

Then when it is all compiled and linked up, the programme now needs admin privileges.  Did I accidentally include soem snippet that means it suddenly needs admin privs?

Theres nothing inheretn in my prog that needs admin privs, it just seems to be adding the version info etc triggers it .. what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid words like "install", "installer", "update", "updater", and others, in the application info (version info), otherwise Windows will automatically ask for privileges elevation if UAC was enabled.